# Error while playing video in android

Tags: android, android-videoview

Hi there hope you are all fine i have a issue when i try to open my video in Video view it Generates the Error VideoView
 `Error: 1,-2147483648` so there any Solution to Fix it plz...

**Video.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Video extends ActionBarActivity {

    String video_src="media";
    String video_file_name="Surah_Rahman.mp4";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
    //  vidView.setVideoURI(video_src+"/"+video_file_name);

        vidView.setVideoPath(video_src+"/"+video_file_name);
        vidView.start();
    }


}
```

LOGKAT

```
11-05 11:06:34.364: I/dalvikvm(920): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    11-05 11:06:34.384: I/dalvikvm(920): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    11-05 11:06:34.444: E/MediaPlayer(920): error (1, -2147483648)
    11-05 11:06:34.694: E/MediaPlayer(920): Error (1,-2147483648)
    11-05 11:06:34.694: D/VideoView(920): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

This Error: 1,-2147483648 is an unknown error. It's all about the encoding format of your vedio You can see this problem in these Links:
[Can't play mp4 video in my Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849044/cant-play-mp4-video-in-my-android-app)

https://superuser.com/questions/371460/command-encoding-h264-baseline-profile-level-1-with-ffmpeg-and-libx264

[Android MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648)

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html